# multiple case statements not working properly

Tags: mysql

I am trying to buid a query to get a specific output. Here is my requirement:

i have two tables one of which is the extract of biometric machine fingerprint punch details:

i have two tables named as **raw_test** and **calender**

```
mysql> desc raw_test;
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_id        | int(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time_loginout | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc calender;
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| time_loginout | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

raw_test table holds following data:

```
mysql> select * from raw_test;
+--------+---------------------+
| emp_id | time_loginout       |
+--------+---------------------+
|    111 | 2014-01-01 09:40:00 |
|    111 | 2014-01-01 16:00:00 |
|    222 | 2014-01-01 09:45:00 |
|    222 | 2014-01-01 17:04:00 |
|    333 | 2014-01-01 09:10:00 |
|    333 | 2014-01-01 17:10:00 |
|    444 | 2014-01-01 09:32:00 |
|    444 | 2014-01-01 17:40:00 |
|    555 | 2014-01-01 09:40:00 |
|    555 | 2014-01-01 17:50:00 |
|    111 | 2014-01-02 09:21:00 |
|    111 | 2014-01-02 17:20:00 |
|    222 | 2014-01-02 09:11:00 |
|    222 | 2014-01-02 17:30:00 |
|    333 | 2014-01-02 09:10:00 |
|    333 | 2014-01-02 17:10:00 |
|    444 | 2014-01-02 09:18:00 |
|    444 | 2014-01-02 16:54:00 |
|    555 | 2014-01-02 09:14:00 |
|    555 | 2014-01-02 16:40:00 |
|    111 | 2014-01-03 09:13:00 |
|    111 | 2014-01-03 16:30:00 |
|    222 | 2014-01-03 09:12:00 |
|    222 | 2014-01-03 17:40:00 |
|    333 | 2014-01-03 09:11:00 |
|    333 | 2014-01-03 17:10:00 |
|    444 | 2014-01-03 09:10:00 |
|    444 | 2014-01-03 17:22:00 |
|    555 | 2014-01-03 09:18:00 |
|    555 | 2014-01-03 17:21:00 |
|    111 | 2014-01-04 09:20:00 |
|    111 | 2014-01-04 17:12:00 |
|    222 | 2014-01-04 09:30:00 |
|    222 | 2014-01-04 17:11:00 |
|    333 | 2014-01-04 09:43:00 |
|    333 | 2014-01-04 17:42:00 |
|    444 | 2014-01-04 09:32:00 |
|    444 | 2014-01-04 17:23:00 |
|    555 | 2014-01-04 09:21:00 |
|    555 | 2014-01-04 17:54:00 |
+--------+---------------------+
40 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and calender holds data as follows:

```
mysql> select * from calender;
+---------------------+
| time_loginout       |
+---------------------+
| 2014-01-01 09:40:00 |
| 2014-01-01 16:00:00 |
| 2014-01-01 09:45:00 |
| 2014-01-01 17:04:00 |
| 2014-01-01 09:10:00 |
| 2014-01-01 17:10:00 |
| 2014-01-01 09:32:00 |
| 2014-01-01 17:40:00 |
| 2014-01-01 09:40:00 |
| 2014-01-01 17:50:00 |
| 2014-01-02 09:21:00 |
| 2014-01-02 17:20:00 |
| 2014-01-02 09:11:00 |
| 2014-01-02 17:30:00 |
| 2014-01-02 09:10:00 |
| 2014-01-02 17:10:00 |
| 2014-01-02 09:18:00 |
| 2014-01-02 16:54:00 |
| 2014-01-02 09:14:00 |
| 2014-01-02 16:40:00 |
| 2014-01-03 09:13:00 |
| 2014-01-03 16:30:00 |
| 2014-01-03 09:12:00 |
| 2014-01-03 17:40:00 |
| 2014-01-03 09:11:00 |
| 2014-01-03 17:10:00 |
| 2014-01-03 09:10:00 |
| 2014-01-03 17:22:00 |
| 2014-01-03 09:18:00 |
| 2014-01-03 17:21:00 |
| 2014-01-04 09:20:00 |
| 2014-01-04 17:12:00 |
| 2014-01-04 09:30:00 |
| 2014-01-04 17:11:00 |
| 2014-01-04 09:43:00 |
| 2014-01-04 17:42:00 |
| 2014-01-04 09:32:00 |
| 2014-01-04 17:23:00 |
| 2014-01-04 09:21:00 |
| 2014-01-04 17:54:00 |
+---------------------+
40 rows in set (0.00 sec
```

)

here **calender** table is extract of **raw_test** table:
i.e., i have created calender table as follows:

```
create table calender as (select time_loginout from raw_test);
```

and if i execute following query, am not getting expected output:

```
select r.emp_id, 
max(case 
when c.time_loginout >= '2014-01-01 09:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 09:15:00' then 'P' 
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-01 09:15:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 09:30:00' then 'L'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-01 09:30:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 10:00:00' then '1H'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-01 10:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 11:00:00' then '2H'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-01 11:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 12:00:00' then '3H'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-01 12:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 13:30:00' then 'HD'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-01 13:30:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 14:00:00' then 'HD'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-01 14:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 17:00:00' then 'FD' 
else 'EO' end)'01',
max(case 
when c.time_loginout >= '2014-01-02 09:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 09:15:00' then 'P' 
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-02 09:15:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 09:30:00' then 'L'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-02 09:30:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 10:00:00' then '1H'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-02 10:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 11:00:00' then '2H'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-02 11:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 12:00:00' then '3H'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-02 12:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 13:30:00' then 'HD'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-02 13:30:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 14:00:00' then 'HD'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-02 14:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 17:00:00' then 'FD' 
else 'EO' end)'02',
max(case 
when c.time_loginout >= '2014-01-03 09:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 09:15:00' then 'P' 
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-03 09:15:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 09:30:00' then 'L'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-03 09:30:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 10:00:00' then '1H'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-03 10:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 11:00:00' then '2H'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-03 11:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 12:00:00' then '3H'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-03 12:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 13:30:00' then 'HD'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-03 13:30:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 14:00:00' then 'HD'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-03 14:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 17:00:00' then 'FD' 
else 'EO' end)'03',
max(case 
when c.time_loginout >= '2014-01-04 09:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 09:15:00' then 'P' 
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-04 09:15:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 09:30:00' then 'L'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-04 09:30:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 10:00:00' then '1H'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-04 10:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 11:00:00' then '2H'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-04 11:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 12:00:00' then '3H'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-04 12:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 13:30:00' then 'HD'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-04 13:30:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 14:00:00' then 'HD'
when c.time_loginout > '2014-01-04 14:00:00' and c.time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 17:00:00' then 'FD' 
else 'EO' end)'04'
from raw_test r left join calender c on r.time_loginout=c.time_loginout group by r.emp_id;
```

output of above query:

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+
| emp_id | 01   | 02   | 03   | 04   |
+--------+------+------+------+------+
|    111 | FD   | L    | P    | L    |
|    222 | EO   | P    | P    | L    |
|    333 | P    | P    | P    | EO   |
|    444 | EO   | L    | P    | EO   |
|    555 | EO   | P    | L    | L    |
+--------+------+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

actually am looking out for each emp_id can be one of the following:

```
P - present
L - late
EO - eary out
1H - 1 hour late
2H - 2 hour late
3H - 3 hour late
HD - half day late
FD - full day late
```

but, emp_id 111 punched by 9:40, and its showing FD which supposed to show 1H.

Please help me in this regard.
Thanking you.

Comment: emp_id 111 also punched at 2014-01-01 16:00:00. Therefore, the CASE statement for '01' column would return FD as well. Since, a MAX is done on the CASE statement, FD is returned (and not 1H).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for check in times only you want the min not the max.  Also I see no need for your second table calendar.  In this example it doesn't seem to be doing anything.  Try this:

```
select emp_id, 
MIN(case 
when time_loginout >= '2014-01-01 09:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 09:15:00' then 'P' 
when time_loginout > '2014-01-01 09:15:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 09:30:00' then 'L'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-01 09:30:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 10:00:00' then '1H'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-01 10:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 11:00:00' then '2H'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-01 11:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 12:00:00' then '3H'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-01 12:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 13:30:00' then 'HD'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-01 13:30:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 14:00:00' then 'HD'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-01 14:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-01 17:00:00' then 'FD' 
else 'EO' end)'01',
MIN(case 
when time_loginout >= '2014-01-02 09:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 09:15:00' then 'P' 
when time_loginout > '2014-01-02 09:15:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 09:30:00' then 'L'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-02 09:30:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 10:00:00' then '1H'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-02 10:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 11:00:00' then '2H'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-02 11:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 12:00:00' then '3H'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-02 12:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 13:30:00' then 'HD'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-02 13:30:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 14:00:00' then 'HD'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-02 14:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-02 17:00:00' then 'FD' 
else 'EO' end)'02',
MIN(case 
when time_loginout >= '2014-01-03 09:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 09:15:00' then 'P' 
when time_loginout > '2014-01-03 09:15:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 09:30:00' then 'L'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-03 09:30:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 10:00:00' then '1H'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-03 10:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 11:00:00' then '2H'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-03 11:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 12:00:00' then '3H'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-03 12:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 13:30:00' then 'HD'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-03 13:30:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 14:00:00' then 'HD'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-03 14:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-03 17:00:00' then 'FD' 
else 'EO' end)'03',
MIN(case 
when time_loginout >= '2014-01-04 09:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 09:15:00' then 'P' 
when time_loginout > '2014-01-04 09:15:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 09:30:00' then 'L'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-04 09:30:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 10:00:00' then '1H'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-04 10:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 11:00:00' then '2H'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-04 11:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 12:00:00' then '3H'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-04 12:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 13:30:00' then 'HD'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-04 13:30:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 14:00:00' then 'HD'
when time_loginout > '2014-01-04 14:00:00' and time_loginout <= '2014-01-04 17:00:00' then 'FD' 
else 'EO' end)'04'
from raw_test  group by emp_id;
```